# Empty statement after while '(' Expected Error

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

For the program I am writing I have to generate prime numbers between 2 and a number over 50 that the user enters what I am trying to do is execute a loop that will start at 2 and go up to what the user entered then Inside i made a loop that loops between 2 and the current number that is needed to be prime and if at any point it divides equally it sets a boolean to false to later be printed wether the number is prime or not but i have not yet put where the number will be printed yet because i am stuck on an error that is telling me **Empty statement after while '(' Expected Error** if it helps i am using net beans

```
    package assignment_4_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_4_1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number above 50 to find all of the primes between 1 and that number: ");
        int firstNum = input.nextInt();
        int primecalc = 1;
        int index = 2; 
        boolean secondloop;
        secondloop = true;

        while(primecalc <= firstNum)
        {
        while (index >= primecalc;)  //the error is on this line
            {
                if(index%primecalc == 0)
                {
                    secondloop = false;
                }
                index++;
            }
        primecalc++;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad semicolon here

```
while (index >= primecalc;) // <-- here
```

remove it

```
while (index >= primecalc) // <-- like so
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
while (index >= primecalc;)
```

to

```
 while (index >= primecalc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following:

> while (index >= primecalc;)

to

> while (index >= primecalc)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while (index >= primecalc)
```

instead of  `(index >= primecalc ;)`

The ; is used at the end of statements.

Comment: The error is a compilation issue, not value related.